# Proper path manipulation in PHP

Tags: php

Here are some things I have done in PHP:

```
$normalizedPath = rtrim($path, '/');
$fullPath = $path . '/' . $basename;
```

Is there a better class or function to do this where I do not need to hardcode `/` into my application? Hopefully this will work with unicode and CJK characters.

Answer (score 0):

No there are no functions to assemble a path.

Since PHP supports both, the Windows style paths and the UNIX style paths, the `rtrim()` statement will not work if `$path` is a Windows style path. You can use `realpath()` to work around this, but `realpath()` has the drawback that it returns an absolute path which might be not desired and it returns `false` for non existing paths, which might be a problem as well in cases were you build a path for something that should be created but does not already exist.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [realpath()](https://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) function.

Check [pathinfo](https://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) function too, it may be useful